# Adding data to an empty custom field via apex code

Tags: custom-field

When I create an custom object I also creating custom fields for this custom object,
the custom field is created empty without any data or value just an empty custom field.
I need help with **how can I add data to the custom field in time of creation the custom field?**
what is the correct apex code to do such a thing I tried a lot of stuff but not working.

Comment: did you look at the default value option on the custom field definition; this would let you default a value to a constant or to a formula based on contextual values such as properties of a running user

Answer (score 3):

Salesforce does not provide a feature to populate a new custom field on existing records.

The exceptions are formula fields (which are re-calculated every time the field is accessed via the UI or query) and possibly roll-up summary fields.

The most appropriate tool to populate new fields on existing records is likely something like the Salesforce-provided DataLoader or dataloader.io (which can handle millions of records)